# Javascript library for creating a password protected zip

Tags: javascript, adobe

Is there any javascript third party library available to convert a file into a  password protected zip file?.Or is there any feature available in Adobe campaign to convert a file into a password protected zip file.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to have library for this.

You can use JSAPI **execComand()**, **7zip** and underlying OS scripting functionality.

For windows:

```
    var toZip = 'cmd /C for %A in ("'+getOption("path_to_files")+'*.csv") do "c:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe" a "%A.zip" "%A" -pYOUR_PASSWORD';
    var zipped = execCommand(toZip,true);
    logInfo('***** ZIP - ' + zipped);
```

You can use aswell the  **External task** activity but it has been deprecated in newer versions.

[7zip a command explained](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/add.htm)

Marcel